# Google Sheet Function for Get Median of a Number Conditionally

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am programing a Google Sheet to summarize data from another Google Sheet.

The sheet containing data is called "Sales"

In the sales sheet, each row represents a sale. It has columns for sales rep name (G column), date of sale (N column), sales class (V column), and Working Days (W column).

I'm trying to write a formula for the following logic.

Calculate Median (working days) from column W values of rows that equal ...

sales rep = "Jane Doe",

sale date is between Jan 1, 2020 and December 31, 2020,

sale classification = "1"

Here is the function I have so far...

```
=MEDIAN(Sales!W:W,(if(Sales!G:G,"Jane Doe",Sales!N:N,">=1/1/2020 00:00:00", Sales!N:N,"<=12/31/2020 23:59:59",Sales!V:V,"1")))
```

I get an error with the above code. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Could you provide a sample sheet, with sample data, to facilitate working on this?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EEcrA61G0Q7Zjfhkvp863Uz9i0QFwGQ9puaRwYwjphc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Have you tried the formula proposed below, in cell B16 of your sample sheet?

Comment: The code below works! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you want?  Note you may need to adjust the range to suit your data:

```
=MEDIAN(QUERY(Sales!G1:W,"select W 
          where G = 'Jane Doe' and 
                V = 1 and 
                N >= date '"&TEXT(DATEVALUE("1/1/2020"),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and 
                N <= date '"&TEXT(DATEVALUE("12/31/2020"),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'",1))
```

If you use just the following, you can check what records it is using:

```
=QUERY(Sales!G1:W,"select G,V,N,W 
          where G = 'Jane Doe' and 
                V = 1 and 
                N >= date '"&TEXT(DATEVALUE("1/1/2020"),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and 
                N <= date '"&TEXT(DATEVALUE("12/31/2020"),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'",1)
```

Let us know if this helps.

Comment: Given your sample sheet, this update to the formula uses the name value in the column heading, rather than hardcoding "Jane Doe".  It can be dragged across from B16 to D16.  ```=MEDIAN(QUERY(Sales!$G$1:$W,"select W 
          where G = '"&B1&"' and 
                V = 1 and 
                N >= date '"&TEXT(DATEVALUE("1/1/2020"),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and 
                N <= date '"&TEXT(DATEVALUE("12/31/2020"),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'",1))```